# Django: Model.objects.filter(a=X, b=Y) not returning desired objects

Tags: django

So I'm trying to query my database for all submissions that have user=request.user and id=12. I know for certain that there are multiple submissions that match this, but filter() only returns one submission. What is wrong with my query?

Thanks

```
Submission.objects.filter(user=request.user, id=puzzleID)
```

Edit:
Thank you to all responders. Here is my model for Submission and Puzzle:

```
class Submission(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
puzzle = models.ForeignKey(
    Puzzle,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
userAnswer = models.TextField()

datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

class Puzzle(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
question = models.TextField()
datetime = models.DateTimeField(
    default=datetime.now,
    blank=True)
# image = models.ImageField()
answer = models.TextField(default="answer")
trials = models.IntegerField(
    default=1,
    validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
subject = models.CharField(
    default="CS",
    max_length=2,
    choices=(
    ("CS", "Computer Science"),
    )
)
```

Edit 2:
Here is also the view in which the query is made

```
    puzzle = Puzzle.objects.get(id=puzzleID)
    form = SubmitForm()
    userTrials = len(Submission.objects.filter(user=request.user, puzzle=puzzle))
    if userTrials >= puzzle.trials:
        limitReached = True
    else:
        limitReached = False
    return render(request, "puzzle.html", {
        "puzzle": puzzle,
        "form": form,
        "userTrials": userTrials,
        "remaining": puzzle.trials - userTrials,
        "limitReached": limitReached,
    })
```

Comment: post your model and also the data from the database with the column names

Comment: there is no problem with your filtering, maybe the puzzleID is giving the wrong value try to `print` it, and tell us the value

Comment: It is an unusual database decision to have a non-unique `id` field. Are you sure there are multiple submissions that match your query? Can you show the `Submission` model definition? There does not appear to be anything wrong with your query, given your stated intent.

Comment: Upon seeing your models, it is as I thought: `Submission` does not define a `primary_key`, so you get `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` [autogenerated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) for you. Primary keys are unique by definition: it is impossible for a table to contain two `Submission` records with id `12`. If you attempted to create such, you will have gotten an `IntegrityError`. Under these circumstances, the query only returning a single result is completely expected.

Comment: @Amadan Yes, you are correct! I realised that I was querying the submission.id, instead of submission.puzzle.id, which was my actual intent. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try querying for puzzle, instead of id, as ID will refer to the submission ID, instead of the puzzle id.

`Submission.objects.filter(user = request.user, puzzle=puzzleID)`